# Using refresh token in graphQL client-side when token has expired

Tags: error-handling, graphql, jwt, access-token, refresh-token

The scenario is:

1. Web app is open but token has expired.
2. User then does some action that makes an api request.
3. GraphQL returns `Error: GraphQL error: unauthorized`.
4. **The app doesn't respond due to the error. Bad user experience.**
5. `onError` from `apollo-link-error` method catches the error and from this am able to call `refreshToken()` (it requires an expired jwt).
6. New token is generated and stored for use.
7. Next user action will go through as per normal.

This is currently my code:

```
const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
  if (graphQLErrors) {
    refreshToken();
  }
});

const link = ApolloLink.from([errorLink, terminatingLink]);
```

How can we improve this flow so that the token is refreshed when the user makes a request without getting an error? Something like the request is 'put on hold' if it causes an error then once token is refreshed, then it will be processed. But I am not sure how to do this.

Or is there any other way we can improve on this flow?

Comment: explore https://github.com/sysgears/apollo-universal-starter-kit/blob/master/modules/authentication/client-react/access/jwt/index.tsx

Answer (score 7):

You can create a Link that can be ran before the operation is executed via your terminating link. You can [create your own stateless link](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/stateless/) but you can also get away with using [setContext](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/context), which can be used to set your request headers while we're at it.

Since you're using a JWT, you can [decode it on the client side](https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode) to extract the expiration value and use that to determine if you need to refresh the token *before* the request is sent to the server. If you weren't using a JWT but the server returned an expiration time with the token, the same strategy would apply.

```
const contextLink = setContext(async () => {
  const { exp } = jwtDecode(jwt)
  // subtracts a minute to account for latency
  const expirationTime = (exp * 1000) - 60000
  if (Date.now() >= expirationTime) {
    await refreshToken()
  }
  return {
    // you can set your headers directly here based on the new token
    headers: {
      ...
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I included an example already. What are you unclear on, @Andres?